# How do the observed values of random effects enter the computation of linear mixed models?

Tags: lme4-nlme, mixed-model

How do the actual values of the random variable $b$, collected from observation, enter into the maximum likelihood computations for the linear mixed effects model?  Specifically, for the model framework below...

**Equations:**

$$ Y_{obs} = \ X_{des} \beta + \ Z_{des}b +\epsilon $$
$$ \epsilon \thicksim N(0,\sigma^2 I_{n}) $$
$$ b \thicksim N(0,\Sigma_{n})$$

**Computational Inputs:**
$$Y_{obs}: \text{vector of observed values of the response}$$

$$X_{des}: \text{matrix of observed values of the vector of predictors }\beta$$

$$Z_{des}: \text{design matrix for the random effects variables}$$

***Integrated or optimized out during computation:*** $$\epsilon, \ b$$

**Computational Outputs:** $$\sigma,\Sigma, \beta$$

My problem is, **I don't see where the observed values of the random parameter $b$ enter the computation**.  In none of the expositions I've read does the parameter $b$ appear to "accept" inputs -- it's instead just a part of the mathematical machinery.  I'm looking for a concrete mathematical explanation of this point (formulas or conceptually precise exposition), or a suitable reference that provides this. (I have not found one, after much searching!)

Note:

I'm **not** looking for command syntax or data structures for use in statistical packages that carry out the computations.  Instead, I'm seeking a conceptual/mathematical **explanation** of how the observed data-points for $b$ enter in.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the vignettes for `lme4`, eg. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf? There's a lengthy explanation that might be useful to you.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at 
Alvin C. Rencher, G. Bruce Schaalje. Linear Models in Statistics. John Wiley & Sons, 2008. 

and 

P. McCullagh, John A. Nelder. Generalized Linear Models, Second Edition. Volume 37 of Chapman & Hall/CRC Monographs on Statistics & Applied Probability. CRC Press, 1989.

Comment: @alexforrence, thank you.  Unfortunately, the lmer pdf and lme4-related documents I've seen (such as various publications by D. Bates) do not address this point.  A guess of mine is that the random effects data is used as a starting point for iterative calculation of the $\Sigma$ values.  I don't know if that's right, though.

Comment: @StatsStudent, thank you. I found the first reference online and it gave me the general ideas behind REML.  I could not find the second reference freely available online, and the prices are substantial. Do you know of an online source for it?  Many thanks!